# How filebeat works in case of failure in destination?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

Quoting from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/how-filebeat-works.html)

> "*In situations where the defined output is blocked and has not
>   confirmed all events, Filebeat will keep trying to send events until
>   the output acknowledges that it has received the events*"

My question here is as events will not be delivered and new log lines keeps on coming to a file. Won't this kind of behavior overload the filebeat server?  Will the filebeat still attempts to crawl the file or stops crawling after trying for some time?

If it stops crawling, which settings allows us to specify the behavior like how many times or duration it has to retry?